# jQuery, problema con función para obtener datos de un input y escribirlas en un párrafo

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy aprendiendo algo de **JQuery** y he querido empezar por algo muy básico: obtener el texto de un `input text` y ponérselo a un párrafo (el proceso contrario a este lo he conseguido) pero por lo visto no es justamente al revés del proceso contrario. No veo el error porque está justamente al revés del que SI funciona y no esta yendo. Si alguien experimentado ya en **JQuery** pudiese ver el error tonto que estoy cometiendo se lo agradecería enormemente.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Pruebas Jquery</title>
     <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
        <script>
         // coger texto del parrafo y mostrarlo en el input text (FUNCIONA!!)
         $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#miBoton").click(function(){
           var contenido = $("#miParrafo").text();
    
           $("#miCajaTexto").val(contenido);
           //$("#miCajaTexto").text(contenido);
          });
         }); 
     // coger texto del inputtext y mostrarlo en el parrafo (NO FUNCIONA)
         $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#miBoton2").click(function(){
           var contenido = $("#miCajaTexto").text();
           $("#miParrafo").val(contenido);
          });
         });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col">
        <h1>Pruebas Basicas jQuery</h1>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 bg-primary">
        <p id="miParrafo">Este texto quiero que salga abajo</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 bg-success">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="miBoton">Pulsar</button>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row bg-info">
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="miCajaTexto">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-info" id="miBoton2">Pulsar</button>
       </div>
    
      </div>
     </div>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.val () funciona en elementos de entrada y .text () no funcionará en los elementos de entrada. .val () obtiene el valor del elemento de entrada, independientemente del tipo. .text () obtiene el texto interno (no HTML) de todos los elementos coincidentes: .texto() El resultado es una cadena que contiene el contenido de texto combinado de todos los elementos coincidentes. Este método funciona en documentos HTML y XML. No se puede usar en elementos de entrada. Para el texto del campo de entrada use el atributo val. .val () Obtenga el contenido del atributo de valor del primer elemento coincidente

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#miBoton").click(function() {
    var contenido = $("#miParrafo").text();
    $("#miCajaTexto").val(contenido);
    $("#miParrafo").text(contenido);

  });

  $("#miBoton2").click(function() {
    var contenido = $("#miCajaTexto").val();
    if (contenido != "") {
      $("#miParrafo").text(contenido);
    } else {
      alert("Escriba algo antes de volver a intentar");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pruebas Jquery</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1>Pruebas Basicas jQuery</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 bg-primary">
        <p id="miParrafo">Este texto quiero que salga abajo</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 bg-success">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="miBoton">Pulsar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-info">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="miCajaTexto">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-info" id="miBoton2">Pulsar</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inviértelos: (el `.text()` y `.val()`)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#miBoton2").click(function(){
        var contenido = $("#miCajaTexto").val();
        $("#miParrafo").text(contenido);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

EL problema es que estas inicializando el evento clic de los dos botones dentro del documente ready, y el valor del segundo elemento aun no ha sido digitado. yo lo haria con dos funciones que dejo a continuacion

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pruebas Jquery</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script>
        // coger texto del parrafo y mostrarlo en el input text (FUNCIONA!!)
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        });//fin del  document ready
        
        function miFuncion1(){  
                      var contenido = $("#miParrafo").text();
                $("#miCajaTexto").val(contenido);
                         
        }
            
    function miFuncion2(){
                var contenido = $("#miCajaTexto").val();
                $("#miParrafo").html(contenido);     
            
    }
                     

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h1>Pruebas Basicas jQuery</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 bg-primary">
                <p id="miParrafo">Este texto quiero que salga abajo</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 bg-success">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" id="miBoton" OnClick="miFuncion1()">Pulsar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row bg-info">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control " id="miCajaTexto">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <button class="btn btn-info" id="miBoton2" OnClick="miFuncion2()">Pulsar</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```